# Laravel5: Eloquent and JOIN

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

1. Items Table

   ```
   | id    | item_id | item_title |
   |-------|---------|------------|
   | 1     | 1002    | A          |
   | 2     | 1003    | B          |
   | 3     | 1004    | C          |
   ```
2. Sells Table

   ```
   | id | item_id   |  
   |----|-----------|
   | 1  | 1002 1003 |
   | 2  | 1003 1004 |
   | 3  | 1004 1002 |
   ```

I want result : Sells Table 1. item title is A B

I want to combine the sells table with the item table and then match the item_id of the sells table to the item_title of the item table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table definitions look incorrect, you should have a pivot table linking `items` with `sells`, so a `sell_item` table:

```
item_id | sell_id
-----------------
1       | 1
1       | 3
2       | 1
2       | 2
3       | 2
3       | 3
```

Then using eloquent, you'd create models to represent your tables and define the relationships using `BelongsToMany`:

```
class Item extends Model {
    public function sells() {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Sell::class);
    }
}

class Sell extends Model {
    public function items() {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class);
    }
}
```

Each instance of either model will then have access to it's related models via `$item->sells` and `$sell->items`.

The query builder can perform a join if not going the Eloquent route:

```
DB::table('sells')->join('items', 'sells.item_id', '=', 'items.item_id')
                  ->select('sells.*', 'items.title')
                  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The table definitions look incorrect, If you corrected already then your model replationship should be like

```
class Item extends Model {
    public function sells() {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Sell::class);
    }
}

class Sell extends Model {
    public function items() {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class);
    }
}
```

Each instance of either model will then have access to it's related models via $item->sells and $sell->items.

The query builder can perform a join if not going the Eloquent route:

```
DB::table('sells')->join('items', 'sells.item_id', '=', 'items.item_id')
                  ->select('sells.*', 'items.title')
                  ->get();
```

Or if your model name is `Sell` then

```
$response=Sell::with('items')->get();
```